# Select mysql field depends on other field value

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have 3 tables:

```
currency
id | name
1  | usd
2  | eur

currency_date
id |   date   | usd | eur
1  | 22.09.13 | 10  | 12
2  | 23.09.13 | 11  | 13
3  | 24.09.13 | 9   | 10

cost
id | id_currency | id_currency_date | cost
1  |     1       |       2          |  15
```

So for row with **id=1** in `cost` table we have `usd` with exchange value `11`.

Is it possible to get value of field by name of other field in different table?

I think it need to be something like this:

```
SELECT currency_date.VAR(currency.name) AS cur_val
FROM cost
LEFT JOIN currency ON currency.id = cost.id_currency
LEFT JOIN currency_date ON currency_date.id = cost.id_currency_date
WHERE cost.id = 1
```

**currency_date.VAR(currency.name)** just for showing what I want.

Comment: It would work better if you normalized your data and has separate records in your currency_date table for each currency.  Then a simple join would do the trick.

Comment: You could hard code a solution if you can't normalize.  Do you expect to add many currencies in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
SELECT case currency.name when 'usd' then currency_date.usd when 'eur' then currency_date.eur end AS cur_val
FROM cost
LEFT JOIN currency ON currency.id = cost.id_currency
LEFT JOIN currency_date ON currency_date.id = cost.id_currency_date
WHERE cost.id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, it works... just little edited code with right syntax.